# Why isn't FlashBuilder building with updated code?

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation, flash-builder

I am using FlashBuilder for a project (Actionscript Project, using AS3) that I've been working on for a few weeks now. I took a break for the holidays (naturally), and when I came back, the compiler seemed to stop working. Everytime I ran the default Actionscript application, the swf ran without my new changes.

According to the file system, the swf had been modified (though my SVN software, Cornerstone, detects no difference in the file). But, if I add in a trace statement in the constructor of the default application, it is not displayed in the console while running in debug mode (even though all other statements that were written and saved before today run fine).

I have tried Project->Clean several times. I also have changes the compiler arguments to generate a size report, however, I have another swf that is generated on build (a preloader) and the size report only includes that (even though it does modify the main swf. This even happens after a clean and it MUST generate a new main swf and preloader swf).

I have also restarted FlashBuilder, and the computer, and moved the project to a different computer, all with the same result (build not including updated code)

Any other ideas to get rid of this strange behavior?

Thanks in advance,
-Esa

Comment: Have you deleted the .swf and then rendered it to a new .swf again? It could also be that just after your holiday you made or edited a function that blocks the other (new) code..